# How to use CodePush's(React Native plugin) staging and prod env for Android Play Store's open beta and prod releases?

Tags: android, react-native, code-push

The mechanism suggested in the documentation can ensure that my debug builds use staging deployment key and release build use production key.

But as far as I can understand(please correct me if I am wrong in this understanding), the debug builds would need the packager running and thus can't be shared to potential testers. 
The purpose is for users in the app's beta program on Play Store to get pre-production updates from staging and other users get updates from production. But since the same release build is promoted to prod from open beta in Play Store, they would both ideally have the production deployment key.

The reason *Dynamic Deployment Assignment* wouldn't work is because I can't get a handle to which user has joined the app's beta program on Play Store. Or do I?

[Issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-code-push/issues/494) on the CodePush repo

**EDIT** - One method I can think of is to target releases with versions(which I can adjust according to my knowledge of the version in Play Store's open beta and prod) in addition to environments.
But it would be really elegant if I could leverage the environments for this.